# Switching turn based movement function to automatic

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm doing a project where my program is supposed to show a traffic simulation using PyQt. I have a function that determines the movement of the vehicles and it works through a button press in the GUI where one press is 1 full turn of all the vehicles in the simulation moving. The idea though is for this to be real time so the user only presses the button once for "start simulation" and with that the simulation would run until all the vehicles have reached their destination.

```
def next_full_turn(self):

    for count in range(self.get_number_of_vehicles()):
        self.next_vehicle_turn()
```

The function looks as simple as this because the movement is determined in another function. So it works correctly turn based with just the 2 lines of the for-loop. I tried to add "while self.end == 0" loop to make the function keep going for multiple turns but the program just keeps crashing with this. I created another button that would change the value of self.goal i.e stop the loop. I also tried while i < 100 and += 1 to make a simple while loop that runs for 100 turns but that also crashed. Solution is probably simple but I'm having difficulties grasping the issue.

I'm  completely new to GUI programming, PyQt and the project itself is a huge challenge for me with the scale of it but I'm trying :D

Here is how the button is coded in GUI.py

```
def init_buttons(self):
    
    start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("start simulation")
    start_button.clicked.connect(self.world.next_full_turn)
    self.horizontal.addWidget(start_button)
```

This is the basic movement function:

```
def move(self, direction):

    target = self.get_location().get_neighbor(direction)
    current_square = self.get_location_square()
    target_square = self.get_world().get_square(target)
    self.spin(direction)
    if target_square.is_empty():
        current_square.remove_vehicle()
        self.location = target
        target_square.set_vehicle(self)
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

and lastly this is the function that is used to determine the direction i.e steering

```
def move_body(self, facing):

    location = self.body.get_location()
    facing = self.body.get_facing()
    aim = self.steering(location)
    if aim[0] == facing:
        if self.move_forward(facing):
            return
    if aim[0] == Direction.get_next_clockwise(facing):
        if self.move_right(facing):
            return
    if aim[0] == Direction.get_next_counter_clockwise(facing):
        if self.move_left(facing):
            return
    if aim[1] == facing:
        if self.move_forward(facing):
            return
    if aim[1] == Direction.get_next_clockwise(facing):
        if self.move_right(facing):
            return
    if aim[1] == Direction.get_next_counter_clockwise(facing):
        if self.move_left(facing):
            return
```

Comment: We need to know how that function is called, so please provide a [mre].

Comment: Sry I'm new here but I tried to provide some relevant functions

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you actually want to call `next_full_turn` periodically, right? If that's the case, use QTimer.